# Evaluation order concerning operator -> and ()

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, operator-precedence

Consider this code snippet:

```
std::shared_ptr<...> p = ...;
p->f(std::move(p));
```

According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator ->` and `()` are of the same precedence and are both left-to-right associative. So I presume `p->` is evaluated before `std::move()`, and the snippet should be fine. But VC15 does the opposite and crashes my program. Is this a VC15 bug or I have just got something wrong here?

Comment: The argument evaluation order is unspecified. `f`  has two arguments, one implicit `this` argument and the explicitly specified one. They can be evaluated in any order that suits the compiler, at the moment of compilation. Formally you have UB for reading and modifying an object (somewhere within the smart pointer) in the same expression.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh yes, you're right! I got it! I overlooked this `this` pointer thing. Could you please make it an answer so I can accept and close this question?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf These are function calls and guaranteed not to interleave. Not UB, just unspecified.

Comment: @T.C. Everytime I see your words, I feel safe and warranted. To me, T.C. just seems Technical Committee :)

Comment: @T.C.: C++11 §1.9/15 “If a side effect on a scalar
object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined”. Which sequence of read and write of the raw pointer value is it that you think is guaranteed, and why?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), [...] Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function."

Comment: @T.C. That's a quote but what conclusion do you draw wrt. to my question, which sequence of read and write for the raw pointer do you think is guaranteed?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So, to sum up, one of the possible outcome of the unspecified is UB ~>_<~

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The reads and writes are inside distinct function calls, which are indeterminately sequenced w/r/t to each other. Of course it's unspecified which one will happen first. UB happens only if they are unsequenced, not if they are indeterminately sequenced.

Comment: And when you say "it's unspecified which one will happen first", does that mean "one is sequenced relative to the other", or does it mean, like, "one is unsequenced relative to the other"?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "Evaluations A and B are indeterminately sequenced when either A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but it is unspecified which."

Comment: @T.C. Seems you're right. No UB, just unspecified. It's counter-intuitive but OK.

Comment: The problem is not the std::move, but the initialization of the corresponding parameter with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're invoking undefined behaviour, because the order of evaluation of arguments in a function call is *not* specified by the standard, and with...

```
p->f(std::move(p));
```

You have *two* arguments being passed. First of all, `this`, and secondly, `std::move(p)`. But now, there's a not-so-obvious problem. You're *both* reading *and* writing to the same shared pointer. This can lead to basically anything, otherwise known as undefined behaviour. Let's not even mention you're using `std::move()` on such a pointer...

`*this` is pointing to `*p`, but the first (explicit) argument now holds the pointer itself, so `*p` is not valid! Let's suppose this didn't crashed the program (somehow...). Then, this can lead to the object itself being destroyed as soon as `f` is left. But... when the shared pointer (assuming just a single reference is left) and thus the object itself is destroyed, the function has *not* still left. Again, just problems...

That was just an example, and anything could have happened in the middle of anything. Just *don't* read **and** write in the same expression and you'll be okay :).

**BTW**: [We all know VS is all but standards-complaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599960/visual-c-standards-compliance), but anyway, this has nothing to do with the order and precedence of operator resolution.

**Edit**: Everything is okay **if** `f()` takes a universal reference (a.k.a: forwarding reference, a.k.a collapsed-rvalue-reference-black-magic-that-somehow-got-into-the-standard) or a rvalue reference. So, for example...

```
void f(std::shared_pointer<...> &&ptr)
```

Everything will go beatiful and perfect, <sub>as long as you don't do bad things with `ptr`...</sub>

**But**, if `f` takes an object of type `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>>`, the shared pointer is moved on to its argument and all the above stuff happens.

Comment: Worth noting that whether this is UB or not depends on whether f takes a shared pointer though. If it takes a forwarding reference for example, nothing bad happens.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: That's an important point. I'm adding it to the answer.